# How to bind data from two tables in PhoneJs?

Tags: javascript, html, devexpress, datasource, phonejs

I have two tables:

- `nom_articole` { id(PK), denumire, nom_um_id(FK) }
- `nom_um` { id(PK), simbol, denumire }

I want to display:

- nom_articole.id
- nom_articole.denumire
- nom_um.simbol

My html code:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'nom_articoleDetails', title: 'Nom_articole' } " >
<div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
    <div data-bind="dxScrollView: { }">
        <h2 data-bind="text: nom_articole.denumire"></h2>
        <div class="dx-fieldset">
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">ID</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value" data-bind="text: nom_articole.id"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Denumire</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value" data-bind="text: nom_articole.denumire"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">U.M.</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value" data-bind="text: ????????????????"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-options="dxContentPlaceholder : { name: 'view-footer', transition: 'none' } " ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascrip code:

```
MobileApplication.nom_articoleDetails = function(params) {
return {
    id: params.id,
    //nom_um: new MobileApplication.nom_umViewModel(),
    nom_articole: new MobileApplication.nom_articoleViewModel(),

    handleDelete: function() {
        DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "Delete item").then($.proxy(function (result) {
            if (result)
                this.handleConfirmDelete();
        }, this));
    },

    handleConfirmDelete: function() {
        MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.remove(params.id).done(function() {
            MobileApplication.app.navigate("nom_articole", { target: "back" });
        });
    },

    viewShown: function() {
        nom_articoleDetails = this;
        MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.byKey(params.id).done(function(data) {
            nom_articoleDetails.nom_articole.fromJS(data);
        });
    }
};
```

This code was generated by Devexpress multi-channel application wizard.

Comment: What is the issue? Does this code cause any error? Please clarify.

Comment: no, its working, just i cant bind the nom_um.simbol to the third dx-field-value.(i hawe no idea how)

Answer (score 1):

From the information you gave, and provided that `nom_articole` and `nom_um` share the same key, the code would be:

```
viewShown: function() {
    // ... your code ...

    MobileApplication.db.nom_um.byKey(params.id).done(function(data) {
        nom_articoleDetails.nom_um.fromJS(data);
    });
}
```

You uncomment the `nom_um` member and use `text: nom_um.simbol` as the binding text in the view.

**Update:**

To load an object by foreign key, you have two options. The first is cascading fetches:

```
MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.byKey(19).done(function (data) { 
    nom_articoleDetails.nom_articole.fromJS(data); 

    MobileApplication.db.nom_um.byKey(data.nom_um_id).done(function(data) {
        nom_articoleDetails.nom_um.fromJS(data);
    });
});
```

The second will work if your data service is properly configured OData. In this case you may use the *expand* feature:

```
MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.byKey(19, { expand: "nom_um" }).done(function (data) { 
    // data will contain a nested object
});
```

P.S. DevExpress provides Support service, and in case you cannot find the right answer here, you can ask them and share the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to return from the second table not by id but nom_um_id, Something like this:    `viewShown: function (){
            nom_articoleDetails = this;
            MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.byKey(19).done(function (data) {
                nom_articoleDetails.nom_articole.fromJS(data);
            });         
            MobileApplication.db.nom_um.byKey(MobileApplication.db.nom_articole.byKey(19).nom_um_id).done(function (data) {
                nom_articoleDetails.nom_um.fromJS(data);
            });
            }`  But it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I have changed the viewShown as you mentioned in the first solution but I get this error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined', line 41, file 'http://localhost:60252/views/nom_articole/nom_articole-details.js'. Here the 'data' is the data in this sequence '... byKey(data.nom_um_id) ...'